# Uploading files from one remote server to another in Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby, file, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a project to deploy with Capistrano 3.3.3. There are two different server machines: one is a webserver(role :app), the other is DB (role :db). On the DB server I have a Apache Solr service, and the devs need to update it's config files. These config files they store in a repository with the rest of project code. During deploy I need to upload this files to DB server to a solr directory. I have a legacy task that makes it.

```
desc 'Solr config update'
task :update_solr_config do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "scp -i /home/user/dbserver.pem #{current_path}/stack/data-config-menu-produccion.xml        user@dbserver:/usr/share/tomcat7/solr/menu/conf/data-config.xml"
    execute "scp -i /home/user/dbserver.pem #{current_path}/stack/data-config-promociones-produccion.xml user@dbserver:/usr/share/tomcat7/solr/promociones/conf/data-config.xml"
    execute "scp -i /home/user/dbserver.pem #{current_path}/stack/data-config-vista-produccion.xml       user@dbserver:/usr/share/tomcat7/solr/vista/conf/data-config.xml"
  end
end
```

But I'm think about what if there will be two DB servers? How have I to modify this task then?

I've read about Capistrano's methods `upload`, `put`, `download`, `get` and `transfer`. But I can't figure it out which of them could do a server-server file transfer. I suggest this task would be applied on :db roles to iterate each server in role.

```
desc 'Solr config update'
task :update_solr_config do
  on roles(:db) do
    ...Some magic goes here...
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: there is no `scp` option to copy a file to many hosts at once, only iteration through a list.

Comment: I know this is not exactly  answering the question that you asked, but I would really consider using a provisioning tool at this point, like chef, ansible, puppet, etc.  I feel similar temptations to do configuration with Capistrano, but if you spearate code deployment from server provisioning, it will be cleaner and more maintainable over time.  I use Chef and it works great, but have also heard good things about Ansible.

Comment: @Зелёный the thing is that I don't want to use `scp`, the question is how can I pull files from web server to db servers using Capistrano.